# How to display or hide R flexdashboard component based on shiny input value?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I want to display or hide an R flexdashboard component based on a Shiny input value. To do this, I'm trying to execute code that creates a new level-3 markdown section dynamically. If I run the following code, I get the expected document with the sidebar and 3 components - i.e., the final code chunk creates the "Section C" component.

````
---
title: "Sample Flexdashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

## Sidebar {.sidebar}
```{r}
radioButtons(
  "select",
  "Show or hide component",
  choices = c("Show" = "show", "Hide" = "hide"),
  selected = "show"
)
```

## Column

### Section A

### Section B

```{r, results='asis'}
cat(paste0("\n",
           "### ",
           "Section C",
           "\n"))
```
````

[image]

However, when I use the following as my final chunk to show/hide Section C based on the "select" input value, it prints the `### Section C` text as code in Section B, rather than creating a new component using that text as markdown.

````
```{r, results='asis'}
renderPrint(
  if (input$select == "show") {
    cat(paste0("\n",
               "### ",
               "Section C",
               "\n"))
    }
  )
```
````

[image]

Perhaps there's a better function to use than renderPrint?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61299368/shiny-and-shinydashboard-how-to-display-inputs-in-sidebar-only-on-certain-tabs/61307993#61307993

Answer (score 0):

My packages are currently incompatible with this flexdashboard with runtime:shiny. So I'm unable to test this solution but am basing it on previous experience.

`cat()` returns a text string. This is why it is interpreted as-is as a new header.

When you put a `if` statement in a section the chunk returns the last object that is run...which is the `if` statement and not the `cat` statement. You can get around this by explicitly returning the object you want after the if statement is complete. And you can set the text to `NULL` if you want nothing returned.

````
```{r, results='asis'}
if (input$select == "show") {
  sec3text <- cat(paste0("\n",
             "### ",
             "Section C",
             "\n"))
  } else {
  sec3text <- NULL
}
sec3text
```
````

`renderPrint()` returns a function that tells shiny or flexdashboard what to print in a box. Because it is not a text string "### Section 3" the flex dashboard interprets it as an object to be rendered. You can see this by assigning the results of a renderPrint to a test variable and then looking at the structure.

```
> test <- shiny::renderPrint("Some print")
> str(test)
function (...)  
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "shiny.render.function" "function"
 - attr(*, "outputFunc")=function (outputId, placeholder = FALSE)  
 - attr(*, "outputArgs")= list()
 - attr(*, "hasExecuted")=Classes 'Mutable', 'R6' <Mutable>
  Public:
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    get: function () 
    set: function (value) 
  Private:
    value: FALSE 
 - attr(*, "cacheHint")=List of 2
  ..$ label       : chr "renderPrint"
  ..$ origUserExpr: chr "Some print"
```

So if you want to the RMD to interpret your text you need to type it as YAML and not as a function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code chunk you provided (with "sec3text") doesn't quite work because input$select needs to be called within a reactive(). Would you be able to elaborate on what it would look like to type the text as YAML, instead of as a function?